# Regex to match a string containing as many digits as letters

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex to match a string with the following criterion:

1. the string must contain an even number of chars
2. the string must contain as many digits as letters

Should match:

- A3D4
- A34DF5
- 22FF

I tried, but didn't get a solution. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using regexp to keep only letters or only numbers and comparing them :
(example in javascript)

```
var str = 'A34DF5';
var result = str.replace(/[^a-z]/gi,'').length == str.replace(/[^0-9]/gi,'').length ;
```

Answer (score 4):

If the programming language you're using supports [regex subroutines](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html), then the following one should suit your needs:

```
^([A-Z](?1)*[0-9]|[0-9](?1)*[A-Z])+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/LMvf5pQX6TsXKu0h)

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vG3aP7/1)

Comment: Beautiful regexp :)
(but doesn't match A23B)

Comment: Yep, the `+` fixes it, Sly. Or here's a more efficient version with less backtracking `^(?:([A-Z](?1)*[0-9])|([0-9](?2)*[A-Z]))+$`

Comment: @Sly This is a nice fix, thank you, I updated my answer.

Comment: @Zantier I'm not sure yours is more efficient, since there is actually more recursion (two subgroups). It would be interesting to compare both.

Comment: Mine avoids a lot of redundant matches, which could be useful if the input is large. For example, with the input `A1A1A1A1A1A1A1A1A1A1A1A1A1`, the "regex debugger" on the left side of regex101.com shows yours taking 73727 steps, and mine taking 100. Of course, unless you really have to use regex, there are much better ways to solve the problem more efficiently.